# Native node.js addon error pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, node.js, objective-c++, node.js-addon

I'm writing a function that looks like this:

```
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> getIconForFile(const char * str) {
  NSImage * icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
  NSData * tiffData = [icon TIFFRepresentation];
  unsigned int length = [tiffData length];

  //TODO this is causing `malloc: *** error for object 0x10a202000: pointer being freed was not allocated`
  char * iconBuff = (char *)[tiffData bytes];

  Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> ret = Nan::NewBuffer(iconBuff, length);

  return ret;
}
```

It works as expected except when it gets run by node.js, it throws `malloc: *** error for object 0x10a202000: pointer being freed was not allocated`. I've tried different things using `malloc`, etc but nothing is working. I understand that `Nan::NewBuffer` is trying to free the buffer data somehow and that's where the problem is coming from. Maybe the `iconBuff` variable is allocated to the stack and when it goes out of scope and `Nan::NewBuffer` tries to free it, it's freeing a null pointer? I'm not sure and I'm sort of lost :(

---

Here's the code that "fixed" it but @uliwitness pointed out in his answer that it still has memory management problems:

```
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> getIconForFile(const char * str) {
  NSImage * icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
  NSData * tiffData = [icon TIFFRepresentation];
  unsigned int length = [tiffData length];

  char * iconBuff = new char[length];
  [tiffData getBytes:iconBuff length:length];

  Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> ret = Nan::NewBuffer(iconBuff, length);

  return ret;
}
```

---

Here's the specific code I ended up going with based on @uliwitness' answer:

```
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> getIconForFile(const char * str) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSImage * icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:str]];
    NSData * tiffData = [icon TIFFRepresentation];
    unsigned int length = [tiffData length];

    return Nan::CopyBuffer((char *) [tiffData bytes], length);
  }
}
```

This seems to be the most elegant solution and from some quick and dirty testing, seems to result in a smaller resident set size in node.js over many invocations, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: I encountered a similar error, which turned out to be a bug in NodeJS code, not my code. There are a bunch of GitHub issues linked from/to https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/33508. Upgrading my addon to the latest `bindings` and `node-addon-api` packages fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled  for documentation about `Nan::NewBuffer`, and found this page: https://git.silpion.de/users/baum/repos/knoesel-mqttdocker-environment/browse/devicemock/node_modules/nan/doc/buffers.md

This says:

> Note that when creating a Buffer using Nan::NewBuffer() and an
>   existing char*, it is assumed that the ownership of the pointer is
>   being transferred to the new Buffer for management. When a
>   node::Buffer instance is garbage collected and a FreeCallback has not
>   been specified, data will be disposed of via a call to free(). You
>   must not free the memory space manually once you have created a Buffer
>   in this way.

So the code in your own answer is incorrect, because a buffer created using `new char[]` needs to be disposed of using `delete []` (this is different from `delete`, FWIW), however you're giving it to a function that promises to call `free` on it. You're just accidentally turning off the error message, not fixing the error.

So at the least, you should use `malloc` instead of `new` there.

This page also mentions another function, `Nan::CopyBuffer()`, which it describes as:

> Similar to Nan::NewBuffer() except that an implicit memcpy will occur
>   within Node. Calls node::Buffer::Copy(). Management of the char* is
>   left to the user, you should manually free the memory space if
>   necessary as the new Buffer will have its own copy.

That sounds like a better choice for your original code. You can pass it the `NSData`'s `bytes` and it will even do the copying for you. You don't have to worry about "manually freeing the memory space", as the memory is owned by the NSData, which will take care of disposing of it when it is released (If you're using ARC, ARC will release the NSData, if you're not ARC, you should add an `@autoreleasepool` so it gets released).

PS - At the bottom of that page, it also mentions that you could use a `Nan::FreeCallback` and pass it to `Nan::NewBuffer`. If you provide one there that calls `delete []` on the buffer it is given, the code from your answer would work as well. But really, why write additional code for something `Nan::CopyBuffer` will apparently already do for you?

Comment: I've implemented what you said and it's working, thanks! Is there a way to verify that it's working as expected and that there aren't errors getting swallowed? It seems to me like the code I posted would cause a memory leak correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could leak memory, it could format your hard drive. That's the mean thing about memory management, all bets are off once things have gone wrong.

Comment: In the case of a plain-old-data type like an array of chars and an OS where `operator new` is implemented using `malloc` under the hood, it might even work fine by accident. But in the case of a C++ class, the least result of `free`ing something allocated using `new` would be one or more destructors not being called and it leaking. If `new` is implemented differently than `malloc`, it may overwrite memory and cause random things to happen the next time someone tries to use the overwritten memory.